# Can't break out of the loop where i want

Tags: python

I tried to program a chatbot. Everything works great for the most part, but if I want to break out of my loop with the word 'bye', the program generates an answer from the 'randomanswers' list. What can I do to only have my print command as output? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
import random

print("Welcome to Chatbot! Have fun.")
print("")
randomanswer = ['Thats not good', 'me too', 'how about you?']
reactionanswer = {'hello': 'hello, whats up?',
                  'sad': 'speak to me',
                  'entertainment': 'how can i entertain you?'}
userinput = ''
while True:
    if userinput == 'bye':
        print("See you soon!")
        break
    else:
        userinput = input("Question/Answer: ")
        userinput = userinput.lower()
        usersplit = userinput.split()
    
        for i in usersplit:
            if i in reactionanswer:
                print(reactionanswer[i])
            else:
                print(random.choice(randomanswer))
```

Comment: Move `userinput = input("Question/Answer: ")` to _before_ `if userinput == 'bye':`

Comment: You call `input` only after you check if it is bye

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are checking for `'bye'` after the next loop iteration, which is after checking it in the list `reactionanswer`, this it executes this `print(random.choice(randomanswer))`

Try doing

```py
import random

print("Welcome to Chatbot! Have fun.")
print("")
randomanswer = ['Thats not good', 'me too', 'how about you?']
reactionanswer = {'hello': 'hello, whats up?',
                  'sad': 'speak to me',
                  'entertainment': 'how can i entertain you?'}
userinput = ''
while True:
    userinput = input("Question/Answer: ")
    userinput = userinput.lower()

    if userinput == 'bye':
        print("See you soon!")
        break

    usersplit = userinput.split()

    for i in usersplit:
        if i in reactionanswer:
            print(reactionanswer[i])
        else:
            print(random.choice(randomanswer))
```

Comment: You're the best! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you follow the flow of the while loop, you can see it goes directly into 'else:' section. It is better to ask input just after while loop started!